# How to assemble two quantum circuits which has each own qubit mapping state?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I'm curious about something.
I tried to do some qubit mapping using SABRE algorithm. Suppose I have two quantum circuits and apply SABRE algorithm to both of them. Then each of them has its own qubit mapping states. After that, I want to compose them to make it as one long quantum circuit. How can I do it?
I used python code and `qiskit`. I have already searched `qiskit` API and used some functions (compose, combine, append). But the circuits could not be combined. How can I assemble two quantum circuit which have different qubit mapping state respectively?

Thank you

Comment: Would you be able to share exactly where you were experiencing difficulties? Some code snippets highlighting your problems would be pretty helpful

Comment: I upload my new question please kindly check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to composed circuit is the following. Given `circuit1` and `circuit2`, you can do like this:

```
circuit = circuit1 + circuit2
```

You can also do that with transpiled circuits:

```
transpiled1 = transpile(circuit1, backend, routing_method='sabre')
transpiled2 = transpile(circuit2, backend, routing_method='sabre')

circuit = transpiled1 + transpiled2
```

Notice that the circuits to composed need to be the same size. After transpilation, that is ensured. `transpile` will make the circuit as big as the backend (given that you use the same backend during transpilation). The operation `+` will wire the links one-to-one.

Here is an example to compose circuit with different sizes:

```
circuit1 = QuantumCircuit(5)
circuit1.mcx([0, 1, 3, 4], 2)
print(circuit1)
circuit2 = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit2.cx(0, 1)
print(circuit2)
```

```
          
q_0: ──■──
       │  
q_1: ──■──
     ┌─┴─┐
q_2: ┤ X ├
     └─┬─┘
q_3: ──■──
       │  
q_4: ──■──
          
          
q_0: ──■──
     ┌─┴─┐
q_1: ┤ X ├
     └───┘
```

In this case, you need to use `compose(..., qubits=...)`. The parameter qubits indicates how to wire the circuits.

```
circuit = circuit1.compose(circuit2, qubits=[3,2])
print(circuit)
```

```
q_0: ──■───────
       │       
q_1: ──■───────
     ┌─┴─┐┌───┐
q_2: ┤ X ├┤ X ├
     └─┬─┘└─┬─┘
q_3: ──■────■──
       │       
q_4: ──■───────
```

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. But I already did '+' operation too. I think you misunderstand what I said. I will modify my question and upload my real question here later.